# Can't install Steam on 16.10

Tags: nvidia, steam, 16.10

I tried to install Steam on a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.10 (amd64) with proprietary nvidia-drivers. I used `sudo apt-get install steam` in a terminal. The icon apears and i can start Steam. But if the download starts (into the application-window) nothing happens... (to be clear: I'm not talking about a game-download)

(The internet connection works fine.)

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`
Removes a library that steam uses, and makes steam use the system library. This fixes **non proprietary** drivers, but **might** also fix proprietary ones. This is more of a temporary fix, but hope this helps!